# Vertically centering text on a page doesn't work?

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\setstocksize{8.5in}{3.6666in}
\settrimmedsize{8.5in}{3.6666in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{9.0in}{32pc}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.37in}{*}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.1in}{*}{1}
\setheadfoot{0pt}{0pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{0pt}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{vplace}[1]
test
\end{vplace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this a minimal example? Everything in your preamble has nothing to do with the problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment, as you've discovered, is clearly broken. For now, you can work around it with

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\null
\begin{vplace}[1]
test
\end{vplace}
\end{document}
```

I'll contact Lars about the problem.

Comment: Heh, beat me to it.

Comment: while you're talking to Lars, could you ask him to check out the proportionality? I've just noticed that with [0.5] the proportions aren't quite right, and with [1], the text definitely *appears* a bit "low on the page", maybe by about one \baselineskip?

Comment: @daleif: So sorry, Lars, I didn't mean to talk past you, just didn't realise you were you...

Comment: I think (from writing similar code years ago) that you're right that the output will be off by one `\baselineskip`. But I'm too lazy to do the measurements and trial'n'error to get it right :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add `\hrule height0pt` before the `\begin{vplace}`. From reading the documentation, it seems like it should work, but it doesn't. It looks like a bug in `memoir` to me.

```
\newenvironment{vplace}[1][1]{%
  \par\vspace{\stretch{#1}}%
}{%
  \vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
  \par}
```

I think that should be

```
\newenvironment{vplace}[1][1]{%
    \par
    \vspace*{\stretch{#1}}
}{%
    \par
    \vspace{\stretch{1}}%
}
```

Comment: Good point about using \vspace* in there (which I missed at first!). That's probably the best redefinition.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed in the next memoir release

/daleif

Comment: Shouldn't that be "\daleif"?